# How do display different runs in TensorBoard?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

TensorBoard seems to have a feature to display multiple different runs and toggle them.

[image]

How can I make multiple runs show up here and how can assign a name to them to differentiate them?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

In addition to TensorBoard scanning subdirectories (so you can pass a directory containing the directories with your runs), you can also pass multiple directories to TensorBoard explicitly and give custom names (example taken from the --help output):

```
tensorboard --logdir=name1:/path/to/logs/1,name2:/path/to/logs/2
```

More information can be found at the [TensorBoard documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/README.md#runs-comparing-different-executions-of-your-model).

In recent versions of TensorBoard, aliasing this way requires a different argument, however its use is discouraged (quote from current documentation on github - linked above):

> **Logdir & Logdir_spec (Legacy Mode)**
>
> You may also pass a comma separated list of log directories, and
> TensorBoard will watch each directory. You can also assign names to
> individual log directories by putting a colon between the name and the
> path, as in
>
> `tensorboard --logdir_spec name1:/path/to/logs/1,name2:/path/to/logs/2`
>
> **This flag (--logdir_spec) is discouraged and can usually be avoided.**
> TensorBoard walks log directories recursively; for finer-grained
> control, prefer using a symlink tree. Some features may not work when
> using --logdir_spec instead of --logdir.

Comment: note: home directory shortcut (`~`) is apparently not resolved correctly, use full name

Comment: that's more of a shell thing than a tensorflow thing - ~ has to be at the start of a "shell word" (for example, following a space outside of quotes). In here, you can use $HOME instead.

Comment: `~` works for me so likely it has been fixed in later tensorflow versions.

Comment: For recent TensorBoard versions (I'm using 2.3 at the moment, not sure when the change happened exactly), see [@Oren's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62377763/3214872) below, `--logdir` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Why is `--logdir_spec` discouraged, specifically? It's very powerful when comparing a new run to some base "current best" run.

Comment: I'm not sure for other people but using --logdir didn't work for me and I couldn't figure out why until I removed dashses from my run name sub-folder and used underscores instead. For anyone running into that issue hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 96):

I found the answer to my own question on github (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1548).

You need to put your logs in a subfolder e.g. /logs/run1/ and then run tensorboard on the root folder e.g. /logs/.

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: `put your logs in a subfolder e.g. /logs/run1/` - how to do that? manually?

Comment: @liang you probably already have this sub-folder if you created a LOG folder when creating the callback, just run the command as stated above in this folder.

Answer (score 36):

**New version** of tensorboard changed ***logdir*** to ***logdir_spec***:

```bash
tensorboard --logdir_spec=name1:/path/to/logs/1,name2:/path/to/logs/2
```

But really my real advice it to use [wandb](https://wandb.ai/site) instead of tensorboard

Comment: This appears to be wrong, and indeed --logder_spec is discouraged (follow the link to the documentation on github in the accepted answer).

Comment: Hi, he is asking specifcally for manually inserting different runs. logdir is for telling tensorboard to search iterativly for all runs. If you want to give a name for each run and constraine the directories, you need to use logdir_spec. I agree that it is written a bit strange.. And maybe it is discouraged, but this is what he asks for...

Comment: This works for me! Apparently the `--logdir` no longer works, need `logdir_spec` instead!

Answer (score 3):

It seems that just declaring it like this is ok:

```
writer = SummaryWriter(logdir='/runs/you_tag')
```

Then tensorboard will create a `you_tag` folder below `runs/`, in the meantime, the web application will refresh and find `you_tag`.