# Tensorboard multiple graphs are shown with only one program

Tags: tensorboard

When running an mnist classification program to view in tensorboard it shows multiple graphs even though there is only meant to be one. I get the error message:

[image: The error message]

and the graphs look like:

[image: Graph images]

Comment: There is an option for looking at the graphs with different time scales. It looks like it is currently showing you metrics by training iteration, so multiple trianing runs will be on top of one another. Click on "wall time" and you should see the different training runs relative to when they were actually run (one after the other).

Answer (score 5):

This looks as if it is due to the presence of multiple tensorboard files within the same directory. Presumably, you have run the training many times, each time passing the same `logdir` argument to the `tf.summary.FileWriter` constructor. To solve the problem, delete all of the tensorboard files within the `logdir` you have been writing to and run training again. You should then see only one trace.

If you wish to be able to view multiple runs without any issues, save each run in a different subdirectory within a `summaries` parent directory, e.g. `summaries/run1`, `summaries/run2` etc. Running tensorboard with `logdir=summaries` will then display the runs nicely together, as detailed at [How do display different runs in TensorBoard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182380/how-do-display-different-runs-in-tensorboard) and https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1548 .

Edit: Also, as highlighted by @Engineero in their comment, using the *relative* or *wall* viewing options on the tensorboard browser page will “chain together” runs within the logdir into a time series.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because your writer from new session is keeping dumping new values to the file from the older session. Solution, create a new filewriter.