# How can I set up Tensorboard with an arbitrary number of runs?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard

I have a base folder with multiple runs for Tensorboard inside subfolders, and no bare files in the root folder itself

```
mylogdir  
    run1  
        file1  
        file2
    run2
        file1
        file2
    run3
        file1
        file2
```

I know it is possible to explicitly label and declare each run with
`tensorboard --logdir=name1:/path/to/logs/1,name2:/path/to/logs/2`
As described here: [How do display different runs in TensorBoard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182380/how-do-display-different-runs-in-tensorboard)

However, I have a tool that adds more of these subfolders and I would like to just have everything in the root folder displayed. Just doing logdir='./mylogdir/' results in no runs being displayed. Is there an additional config or setting to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the only file that matters to the Tensorboard recursive crawling is the tfevents file - even if it is not needed for what you are trying to do (IE just view embeddings on projector)

All of your subfolders with runs must contain the tfevents file in order to be included. Doing this fixed the issue.